# error: could not compile `glib-macros` (lib) due to 1 previous error

Tags: rust, gtk4

C:\Users\Евгений.rustup\toolchains\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rustlib\x86_64-pc-windows-gnu\lib\rsend.o: No such file or
directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

error: could not compile `glib-macros` (lib) due to 1 previous error

Comment: Ты уверен, что тебе нужен gtk и gnu toolchain под windows? Я бы взял какой-нибудь egui. Вот на хабре есть статья https://habr.com/ru/articles/722438/